# Calculate hours and minutes from milliseconds on MySQL table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a MySQL table with 3 columns: Name; Month; Milliseconds.
I want to calculate the hours and minutes times a certain value of 2.5 for example.

```
SET @miliseconds = 36000000000;
SET @s = @miliseconds / 1000; 
SET @hours = FLOOR(@s / 3600);
SET @minutes = FLOOR(@s / 60 - @hours * 60); 
SET @seconds = ROUND(@s - @hours * 3600 - @minutes * 60);

SELECT @hours, @minutes, @seconds;
```

This gives the correct hours and minutes upon the givens value, not according  the Milliseconds column. Plus, it doesn't let me select the Name and Month columns. How can I do a msqli query in a php file which gives me the math value of milliseconds on my table upon the criteria of Name, Month, Milliseconds.

My goal is to display it in a html table. I know how can I do it in jQuery, but I don't know how can I serialize it. To serialize it in the table I use the following code:

```
var tr = data
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var tr = $('<tr/>');

$(tr).append("<td>" + data[i].mes + "</td>");
$(tr).append("<td>" + data[i].mills + "</td>");

$('.tableMesA').append(tr);
}
```

But is there a way where I can calculate the first column of "mes" with the value of converting milliseconds to a math value?

Comment: get Milliseconds from DB and convert it it php code

Comment: I have the milliseconds on the DB "I have a MySQL table with 3 columns: Name; Month; Milliseconds"

Answer (score 2):

You just have to repeat the above calculations while you select from the table:

```
select t.*,floor(millisecond / 3600000) as hours, floor(millisecond / 60000) - floor(millisecond / 3600000) * 60 as minutes
from t
```

You can also use the [sec_to_time()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) function as well:

```
select t.*, sec_to_time(floor(milliseconds/1000)) as time
from t
```

Comment: That worked to find hours and minutes, thank you. Now how can multiply those hours and minutes by 2.5?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a different question. Pls ask it in a separate post indicating exactly what you are after!